# Функция Shell в VB 6.0

Tags: файлы, visual-basic

Добро всем времени суток. Скажите, у меня есть переменная типа `String`. После того, как я открываю файл, в эту переменную заносится путь, где лежит этот файл, и потом я пытаюсь запустить этот файл по пути, что лежит в переменной т.е так:

```
Shell(path)
```

Но VB всегда выдает ошибку, что файл не найден.

Answer (score 1):

1. Скобки надо убрать. Но в данном случае дело не в жэтом.
2. Вероятно, файл действительно не существует. Если путь относительный, то он считается относительно `CurDir$()`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить так:

```
sh = shell("start "+path);
```

Comment: А sh - это переменная?

Comment: переменная

Comment: С чего бы `start`? `start` - это команда командной строки, даже не программа.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shell path
```